# How do you deploy a flask or django application using jwilder/nginx-proxy?

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm looking into moving some of our web servers to docker containers. The jwilder/nginx-proxy image looks interesting, and seems to do what we want, but how would one properly deploy a flask application in a container, and have it work with the jwilder/nginx-proxy server? To be clear, the flask application would also be running in a docker container.

In a separate, but related question, how would one do this for a django app?

It looks like there's a popular tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask image, and a similar dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx image. In this setup, from what I understand, the nginx-proxy container would direct traffic to the uwsgi-nginx-flask or django-uwsgi-nginx container. Is this a common way to do this?

The main thought I had was that in such a setup, we're running extra instances of nginx - one for every python/django app. Is this common? Or is it possible/beneficial/common to somehow have the nginx-proxy talk directly to uwsgi within the python app container?

I see that the nginx-proxy image has a `VIRTUAL_PROTO=uwsgi` option that other containers can be started with. Is this something that can be used to make things more efficient? Or is it more effort than it's worth?

Edit: Or is the nginx instance that accompanies the flask/django project beneficial, since it can be used to serve static content, without which, you would need to configure the nginx-proxy image with the location of every project's static files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to have Django have one container, NGINX in separate container, other applications in other containers etc. For that I prefer to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). You can checkout my implementation about using Django + NGINX + PostgreSQL in [here](https://github.com/ruddra/docker-django).(I have not used jwilder/nginx-proxy, instead I have used official NGINX docker image)

But putting NGINX and Python server in same container does not sound that bad. I have used a lightweight alpine based images for deploying python, for example:

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine

# --- Python Installation ---
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
    if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
    rm -r /root/.cache

# --- Work Directory ---
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# --- Python Setup ---
ADD . .
RUN pip install -r app/requirements.pip

# --- Nginx Setup ---
COPY config/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN chmod g+rwx /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx
RUN chgrp -R root /var/cache/nginx
RUN sed -i.bak 's/^user/#user/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN addgroup nginx root

# --- Expose and CMD ---
EXPOSE 5000
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi --chdir /usr/src/app/app & nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Although it looks bit messy, but it works fine. Please checkout my full implementation at [here](https://github.com/ruddra/openshift-python-nginx-pipeline-ci-cd).

Depending on how you want to deploy docker images, you can use either approaches. But using `docker compose` would be the best solution IMHO. And in both setups, you can use NGINX to serve your static contents(no need to configure it for each static file).

Comment: We have multiple domains, all pointing to the same public IP, which the nginx-proxy container handles. It also handles SSL termination, so we want to continue using  it. The way you show above, if I understand correctly, has one nginx instances for every container running an App. I was wondering if this redundancy is necessary, or if the nginx-proxy container can have the only nginx instance, and serve all the apps. Even if possible, I was also wondering if it's even a good idea, or if having one nginx instance per app the smart way to do it.

Comment: I have shown another example at the first paragraph as well. Using docker compose, right now I am serving one Django server via Nginx, but I can use the same instance to serve multiple servers(Multiple Django/Flask etc) as well. Personally I prefer that setup.

Comment: Took a closer look at your GitHub repo. Looks interesting. You run gunicorn in each app container, and connect to that from a single nginx instance, which basically accomplishes what I was hoping. I'll see if I can replicate that using nginx-proxy, but it doesn't sound like I should have any problems. Thanks